# Tag rename request: dissidia-*

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The follow two tags need to be renamed to their full name:

- [dissidia-nt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissidia-nt) -> [dissidia-final-fantasy-nt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissidia-final-fantasy-nt)
- [dissidia-012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissidia-012) -> [dissidia-012-final-fantasy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissidia-012-final-fantasy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but... that's a total of three questions, and neither tag has a wiki or wiki excerpt. Manually changing the tags would've been absolutely fine too.

At any rate, I've merged the tags and created synonyms.

Comment: Thanks! :) I guess I could've just edited them myself had I paid attention and realize there wasn't any wiki information